# JMeter HTML Reporting - Why is "infinity" appearing for throughput and network speed?

Tags: html, jmeter, reporting

This appeared for two larger requests, neither of which failed/errored, in a test case with a single user run.

However, this does not appear for the five-user run of the same test case.

I haven't been able to find any documentation on Apache regarding the appearance of infinity during test runs.

Has anyone faced this? If so, did you find a way to get the reporting tool list the true numeric value?

Example of "infinity" appearing in the statistics.json [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gw1Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have "Infinity" in the statistics.json it means that the relevant [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) has failed somewhere somehow (it hasn't been executed for some reason).

The reason can be found in:

1. [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles), take a look at "responseMessage" column
2. [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

If you want to see where the values are coming from and how the statistics are being built and processed - [increase JMeter's logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for the HTML Reporting Dashboard packages by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard" level="debug" />
```

The easiest way to reproduce the issue is just creating a "bad" request, for example adding a [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler like this:

[image]

it won't be executed because you cannot have `://` characters in the DNS hostname and this transaction will be having "Infinity" values in the statistics.json